# UIStoryboard popViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios5, uistoryboard

I'm using a UISegue in my application to automatically transition between viewcontrollers in my application. I'll call them A and B.

It worked as expected, however when I wanted to pop-back to the A from B, I attempted to call
`[self.navigationController popViewController]` however the B's navigationController property reports null.

---

As a second attempt I attempted to map a button, to a UISegue back to view controller A.
However this just creates a new ViewController.

As a work around, I ended up doing as a work around was to retrieve the `B viewcontroller` from the UIStoryboard and calling `[A.navigationController pushViewController:B]`

At which point, calling `[B.navigationController popViewController]` worked as expected.

This seems wrong, from a storyboard segue how can I return to the previous view controller?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the class of your A and B controllers (whether UIViewController, UITableViewController or UINavigationController), but if you follow the following pattern, it should work.

- In an empty storyboard, insert a UINavigationController. This will bring in two windows to the storyboard, linked with an arrow (a segue). The one on the right should be controller A.
- In A, let's say, you add a button. The button will push B into the navigation stack.
- Then, you add the second controller B, and drag from the button in controller A to controller B, and choose "push" from the popped menu.

If you only use a UIViewController (A) and push B, there is no navigationController to take care of popping.

Hope that help.

Comment: There is no need to drag in a UINavigationController and mess around setting that up if you already have a UIViewController. Instead Select the UIViewController and go to the Editor menu and select Embed In and choose UINavigationViewController and this will set everything up for you.

Comment: @ Scott Sherwood. That is a nice trick. I didn't know that. But one question. When I do that in storyboard, Xcode automatically turns my viewController into a navController and a viewController, linked with a segue. So isn't it basically the same thing?

Comment: Yes it is exactly the same its just a little short cut. The link between the navController and the viewController is called a relationship and is slightly different from a Segue but in principle what you are left with is the same as you suggested.